# How to disable a link using only CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to disable a link using CSS?

I have a class called `current-page` and want links with this class to be disabled so that no action occurs when they are clicked.

Comment: after a lot of googling i got the perfect answer for this question
http://css-tricks.com/pointer-events-current-nav/

Comment: Whether a link should be used or not carries more semantical than presentational value. It should not be disabled through CSS, but through utilizing the `hidden` attribute that is applicable to any HTML element. CSS then can be used to select e.g.`a[hidden]` anchor and style it accordingly.

Comment: @amn but i don't think browsers will display an element with the hidden attribute so styling becomes moot.

Comment: @user1794469 They will if you instruct them to, with CSS, using `display: block`, for instance or some other value for `display`. But `hidden` is not always applicable -- it's for elements that are *irrelevant*, and from the question it is not unclear *why* the link should be disabled. This is probably a case of XY problem.

Comment: Clicking is just one form somebody can interact with a link. Avoiding any event on click is therefore not really disabling the link entirely. Search engines as well will still consider the link.

Comment: @RSK `pointer-events: none` only prevents pointing devices from clicking the link . Pressing tab until the link has the focus and then pressing space will still "click" the link

Answer (score 1451, accepted):

From [this solution](http://css-tricks.com/pointer-events-current-nav/):

```css
[aria-current="page"] {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<a href="link.html" aria-current="page">Link</a>
```

For browser support, please see https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events. If you need to support Internet Explorer, there is a workaround; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10276157/1207195).

Warning: The use of [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events) in CSS for non-SVG elements is experimental. The feature used to be part of the CSS 3 UI draft specification but, due to many open issues, has been postponed to CSS 4.

Comment: You can always use a polyfill for IE support, I find myself needing pointer-events: none frequently.

Comment: Also, this doesnt avoid tabbing to the link then enter.

Comment: If you would style it a bit, so the user can see it's disabled. Give it some opacity: .2

Comment: This now works in all modern browsers including IE 11. If you need support for IE 10 and below, you can use a JavaScript polyfill such as [this one](https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill).

Comment: Important note: This only disables clicking, not the actual link itself. You can still use tab + enter to "click" the link.

Comment: This does not work to disable hyperlinks in print preview in Chrome.

Comment: Use of `pointer-events: none;` is not perfect. It also disables other events such as hover, which is required for display of `title="…"` or tooltips. I found the JS solution is better (using `event.preventDefault();`) along with some CSS (`cursor: default; opacity: 0.4;`) and a tooltip explaining why the link is disabled.

Comment: It's also worth resetting your text color and underlining so it doesn't look like a link anymore:  `color:#000; text-decoration: none;`

Comment: At least on Chrome the "cursor" property is pointless when using "pointer-events: none". AFAIK, it's just ignored. Try to for example set "pointer-events: none; cursor: not-allowed;", and cursor stays at default all the time.

Comment: Any way to change cursor if I use `pointer-events: none;`. I've try to use `cursor: not-allowed;` but it not work.

Comment: Also it doesn't prevent bubbling so if you have an element underneath, that one gets still triggered

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for: pointer-events: none;
It was the missing peace in my puzzle. Thanks a lot.

Comment: warning: `pointer-events: none` means that if something is *behind* the link, that thing will get clicked. so if you use this in fly-out menus, it could result in accidentally clicking on something that is behind (covered up by) the flyout menu.

Comment: Tip: adding `color: unset;` will set the color to whatever the parent style text color is.

Comment: Checkout the following link to customize cursor pointers: https://codepen.io/anweshgangula/pen/YzWOyrq

Comment: If it isn't working for you, add `display: inline-block;`

Comment: This doesn't work. `pointer-events: none` only prevents pointing devices from clicking the link . Pressing tab until the link has the focus and then pressing space will still "click" the link

Answer (score 157):

```css
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="disabled">link</a>
```

Comment: You might need to set the display to inline-block (or something other than inline).

Comment: nice, but beware pointer-events browser support (i.e. < IE11) : http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

Comment: For style, try changing `pointer-events:none;` to `pointer-events:unset;`.  Then, the cursor can be changed to `cursor:not-allowed;`.  This gives a better clue as to what is going on to the user.  Seems to work in FF, Edge, Chrome, Opera and Brave as of today.

Comment: @Sablefoste That doesn't work for me in Chrome 60. The cursor is indeed `not-allowed`, but the link remains clickable.

Comment: This doesn't work. `pointer-events: none` only prevents pointing devices from clicking the link . Pressing tab until the link has the focus and then pressing space will still "click" the link

Answer (score 124):

CSS can only be used to change the style of something. The best you could probably do with pure CSS is to hide the link altogether.

What you really need is some JavaScript code. Here's how you'd do what you want using the jQuery library.

```
$('a.current-page').click(function() { return false; });
```

Comment: Don't forget preventing default behaviors: `function(ev){ ev.preventDefault(); ev.stopPropagation(); return false;`.

Comment: @Idiqual, `return false` does that

Comment: `return false` only works if the action is set using the `href` attribute

Comment: Also this version can be used to disable clicks whilst keeping other pointer events like :hover or :focus! Top answer!

Comment: Although this works in all browsers, it only disabled clicking on a link. Keep in mind many users are used to open links from the context menu or by using the middle mouse button.

Answer (score 35):

CSS can't disable a link. It can inhibit pointer events like clicks, but clicks are not the only way to activate a link. Your options are:

- Don't include the `href` or `onclick` attributes in your `<a>` tag.
- Use `document.querySelector` et al to find the anchor elements you want to disable. Remove their `href` or `onclick` attributes so they no longer have link behavior that can be activated by any method.

Comment: I didn't think of that! Or maybe the attribute didn't exist yet in 2010? In any case it's true that `pointer-events: none` can disable mouse events. However, it doesn't disable the underlying link. In a test I tried in Chrome 81, I can still activate such a link by tabbing to it and typing the return key.

Answer (score 31):

### **Bootstrap Disabled Link**

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg disabled" role="button">Primary link</a>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg disabled" role="button">Link</a>
```

### **Bootstrap Disabled Button but it looks like link**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>
```

Answer (score 22):

You can set the `href` attribute to `javascript:void(0)`:

```css
.disabled {
  /* Disabled link style */
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<a class="disabled" href="javascript:void(0)">LINK</a>
```

Comment: @nickf true, however, this is a neat solution and is better than relying on the poor default IE styling when set to disabled.

Comment: I think it could be a bit more complicated than that.  Here's a solution http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/clear_links_to_1

Answer (score 13):

If you want it to be CSS only, the disabling logic should be defined by CSS.

To move the logic in the CSS definitions, you'll have to use attribute selectors. Here are some examples:

##### Disable link that has an exact href: `=`

You can choose to disable links that contain a specific href value like so:

```
<a href="//website.com/exact/path">Exact path</a>
```

```css
[href="//website.com/exact/path"]{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

#### Disable a link that contains a piece of path: `*=`

Here, any link containing `/keyword/`in path will be disabled:

```
<a href="//website.com/keyword/in/path">Contains in path</a>
```

```css
[href*="/keyword/"]{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

#### Disable a link that begins with: `^=`

The `[attribute^=value]` operator targets an attribute that starts with a specific value. It allows you to discard websites and root paths.

```
<a href="//website.com/begins/with/path">Begins with path</a>
```

```css
[href^="//website.com/begins/with"]{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

You can even use it to disable non-https links. For example:

```css
a:not([href^="https://"]){
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

#### Disable a link that ends with: `$=`

The `[attribute$=value]` operator targets an attribute that ends with a specific value. It can be useful to discard file extensions.

```
<a href="/path/to/file.pdf">Link to pdf</a>
```

```css
[href$=".pdf"]{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

#### Or any other attribute

CSS can target any HTML attribute. Could be `rel`, `target`, `data-custom`and so on...

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">Blank link</a>
```

```css
[target=_blank]{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

#### Combining attribute selectors

You can chain multiple rules. Let's say that you want to disable every external link, but not those pointing to your website:

```css
a[href*="//"]:not([href*="my-website.com"]) {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Or disable links to pdf files of a specific website :

```
<a href="//website.com/path/to/file.jpg">Link to image</a>
```

```css
[href^="//website.com"][href$=".jpg"] {
  color: red;
}
```

#### Browser support

Attributes selectors have been supported since Internet Explorer 7. And the `:not()` selector since Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: How do I disable a link using disabled selector? e.g. <a class="test" disabled href="3">test</a> a:disabled{
  cursor:not-allowed;
}

Comment: This doesn't work. `pointer-events: none` only prevents pointing devices from clicking the link . Pressing tab until the link has the focus and then pressing space will still "click" the link

Answer (score 13):

I used:

```
.current-page a:hover {
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

And that was not enough; in some browsers it still displayed the link, blinking.

I had to add:

```
.current-page a {
    cursor: text !important;
}
```

Comment: I think `a[disabled]:active { pointer-events: none !important; }` is better.

Comment: This doesn't work. `pointer-events: none` only prevents pointing devices from clicking the link . Pressing tab until the link has the focus and then pressing space will still "click" the link

Answer (score 13):

Apply the below class on HTML.

```css
.avoid-clicks {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `pointer-events: none` only prevents pointing devices from clicking the link . Pressing tab until the link has the focus and then pressing space will still "click" the link

Answer (score 10):

One way you could do this with CSS, would be to set a CSS on a wrapping `div` that you set to disappear and something else takes its place.

For example:

```
<div class="disabled">
    <a class="toggleLink" href="wherever">blah</a>
    <span class="toggleLink">blah</span
</div>
```

With a CSS like

```css
.disabled a.toggleLink { display: none; }
span.toggleLink { display: none; }
.disabled span.toggleLink { display: inline; }
```

To actually turn off the `a`, you'll have to replace its click event or `href`, as described by others.

PS: Just to clarify, I'd consider this a fairly untidy solution, and for SEO it's not the best either, but I believe it's the best with purely CSS.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to stick to just HTML/CSS on a form, another option is to use a button. Style it and set the `disabled` attribute.

E.g.
http://jsfiddle.net/cFTxH/1/

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
<style>
    .btn-disable {
        display: inline-block;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `pointer-events: none` only prevents pointing devices from clicking the link . Pressing tab until the link has the focus and then pressing space will still "click" the link

Answer (score 5):

> The **pointer-events** property allows for control over how HTML elements
> respond to mouse/touch events – including CSS hover/active states,
> click/tap events in JavaScript, and whether or not the cursor is
> visible.

That's **not** the only way you **disable a link**, but it is a good CSS way which work in Internet Explorer 10 (and later) and all new browsers:

```css
.current-page {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="current-page">This link is disabled</a>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `pointer-events: none` only prevents pointing devices from clicking the link . Pressing tab until the link has the focus and then pressing space will still "click" the link

Answer (score 4):

I searched the Internet and found no better than [this](https://martinwolf.org/2013/01/22/disable-a-link-with-css/).
Basically, to disable button click functionality, just add CSS style using jQuery like so:

```
$("#myLink").css({ 'pointer-events': 'none' });
```

Then to enable it again, do this

```
$("#myLink").css({ 'pointer-events': '' });
```

It was checked on Firefox and Internet Explorer 11, and it worked.

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this, you can set this in CSS yourself.

Comment: Is JavaScript really required?

Comment: This doesn't work. `pointer-events: none` only prevents pointing devices from clicking the link . Pressing tab until the link has the focus and then pressing space will still "click" the link

Answer (score 3):

You can use this CSS content:

```css
a.button,button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    margin: 5px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 20px 0 #cdcdcd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 20px 0 #cdcdcd;
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 20px 0 #cdcdcd;
}

a[disabled].button,button[disabled] {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    opacity: 0.4;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

a.button:active:not([disabled]),button:active:not([disabled]) {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: #2a2a2a !important;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<button disabled="disabled">disabled!</button>
<button>click me!</button>
<a href="http://royansoft.com" disabled="disabled" class="button">test</a>
<a href="http://royansoft.com" class="button">test2</a>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Why does it need so much more CSS content than previous answers? Is all of it really necessary? If it is necessary, what is the reason?

Answer (score 3):

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}
a.disable{
  pointer-events: none;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://example.com">Normal</a>
<a href="https://example.com" class="disable">Disable</a>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `pointer-events: none` only prevents pointing devices from clicking the link . Pressing tab until the link has the focus and then pressing space will still "click" the link

Answer (score 2):

I combined multiple approaches to provide some more advanced `disabled` functionality. [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/rosskevin/fa3c6180102cfa75df63), and the code is below.

This provides for multiple levels of defense so that *anchors* marked as disable actually behave as such.

Using this approach, you get an anchor that you cannot:

- click
- tab to and hit return
- tabbing to it will move focus to the next focusable element
- it is aware if the anchor is subsequently enabled

1. Include this CSS content, as it is the first line of defense.  This assumes the selector you use is 'a.disabled'.

   ```
   a.disabled {
     pointer-events: none;
     cursor: default;
   }
   ```
2. Next, instantiate this class such as (with optional selector):

   ```
    $ ->
      new AnchorDisabler()
   ```

   Here is the CoffeeScript class:

   ```
    class AnchorDisabler
      constructor: (selector = 'a.disabled') ->
        $(selector).click(@onClick).keyup(@onKeyup).focus(@onFocus)

      isStillDisabled: (ev) =>
        ### since disabled can be a class or an attribute, and it can be dynamically removed, always recheck on a watched event ###
        target = $(ev.target)
        return true if target.hasClass('disabled')
        return true if target.attr('disabled') is 'disabled'
        return false

      onFocus: (ev) =>
        ### if an attempt is made to focus on a disabled element, just move it along to the next focusable one. ###
        return unless @isStillDisabled(ev)

        focusables = $(':focusable')
        return unless focusables

        current = focusables.index(ev.target)
        next = (if focusables.eq(current + 1).length then focusables.eq(current + 1) else focusables.eq(0))

        next.focus() if next


      onClick: (ev) =>
        # disabled could be dynamically removed
        return unless @isStillDisabled(ev)

        ev.preventDefault()
        return false

      onKeyup: (ev) =>

        # 13 is the JavaScript key code for Enter. We are only interested in disabling that, so get out fast
        code = ev.keyCode or ev.which
        return unless code is 13

        # disabled could be dynamically removed
        return unless @isStillDisabled(ev)

        ev.preventDefault()
        return false
   ```

Comment: Hello !!, answer is about `CSS` not `JS` or anything else!

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rbF2g/)**
Try this one

```
$('html').on('click', 'a.Link', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work! The link is still active in Chrome.

Comment: To fix this code, swap the first two parameters passed to on(): $('html').on('click','a.Link',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});

Comment: Hello !!, answer is about `CSS` not `JS` or anything else!

Answer (score 1):

You can also size another element so that it covers the links (using the right z-index): That will "eat" the clicks.

(We discovered this by accident because we had an issue with suddenly inactive links due to "responsive" design causing a H2 to cover them when the browser window was mobile-sized.)

Comment: True, but not for keyboard navigation.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it in CSS:

```css
.disabled{
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="disabled">Google</a>
```

See at:

Please note that the `text-decoration: none;` and `color: black;` is not needed, but it makes the link look more like plain text.

Comment: This doesn't work. `pointer-events: none` only prevents pointing devices from clicking the link . Pressing tab until the link has the focus and then pressing return will still "click" the link

Answer (score 0):

Another trick is to place a invisible element above it. This will disable any hover effects as well

```css
.myButton{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

.myButton::after{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this also

```css
<style>
.btn-disable {
  pointer-events: none !important;
    color: currentColor;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    opacity: 0.6;
    text-decoration: none;       
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>NG</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        .btn-disable {
          pointer-events: none !important;
            color: currentColor;
            cursor: not-allowed;
            opacity: 0.6;
            text-decoration: none;       
        }
        </style>
    <body>
        <div class="btn-disable">
            <input type="button" value="Show">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers on this page are wrong. You can not disable a link with css, period, at least as of November 2023.

You can make it so you can't click the link with the mouse but you can still tab to the link and press return and the link will be "clicked"

Example:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log(e.target.textContent));
});
```

```css
a {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<li><a href="#a">link A</a>
<li><a href="#b">link B</a>
<li><a href="#c">link C</a>
```

[image]

2 imperfect solutions

1. you could add `tabIndex="-1"` and then you can't tab to the link.

   Of course if you pre add it then you've disabled the link for keyboard users. If you add it at runtime then you aren't disabling the link via CSS
2. make a fake link element for each link, via CSS hide one or the other

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log(e.target.textContent));
});

const container = document.querySelector('#container');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  container.classList.toggle('disable-links');
});
```

```css
.disabled-link {
  text-decoration: underline;
  opacity: 25%;
}

.links .disabled-link {
  display: none;
}

.disable-links .disabled-link {
  display: initial;
}

.disable-links a {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="links">
<li><a href="#a">link A</a><span class="disabled-link">link A</span>
<li><a href="#b">link B</a><span class="disabled-link">link B</span>
<li><a href="#c">link C</a><span class="disabled-link">link C</span>
</div>


<button type="button">enable/disable links</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

`pointer-events:none` will disable the link:

```css
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```
<a href="#" class="disabled">link</a>
```

Comment: This is good, but of course, not working if the users uses his keyboard :(

Answer (score -2):

```html
<a href="#!">1) Link With Non-directed url</a><br><br>

<a href="#!" disabled >2) Link With with disable url</a><br><br>
```

Comment: The <a> tag doesn't have a disabled attribute.

Comment: attribute a does not have diisabled attribute

Answer (score -2):

simply use your tab without a link, don't include any link attribute to it.