# How to disable a HTML tag?

Tags: css, html

I want to disable a tag if it's already set -- e.g., disable a menu using `disabled = "true"` or something.

I can remove a tag completely using PHP; but I have already styled it and only  want to disable it. Is it possible?

Comment: What kind of disable? Hide it? Disable the link? Or what?

Comment: @poke i want, that if it is set, onclick it does't do anything. just like text

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-a-link-using-css

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, there is no CSS-only way known to me to disable a link the way you describe.

The only thing that comes to mind is putting an additional, transparent element in front of the link, but that can't be achieved in pure CSS, either.

How about giving it a `href='#' onclick='return false'` when generating them in PHP?

Comment: @Pekka it is something what i want. thanks much.
i even don't need href='#', that's enough onclick='return false';)

Comment: @Syom you're welcome. You should use `href='#'` as well, though, for users who have JavaScript disabled.

Comment: you can use `pointer-events: none;` to disable the link and use more css to make it look disabled

Comment: @Pekka review the last post.. you will find CSS does work.

Answer (score 1):

you could also use the css property `display:none;`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
a.disabled_class_name{
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```