# Removing the href attribute

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, href

I'm trying to write a code for pagination. One function is to disable the current link so it looks like text and to be unclickable. In html page this could be achieved by omitting the href attribute like :

```
<a>Link</a>
```

I couldn't do that in javaScript,

```
AvdonPagination.prototype.manageLinks = function(link){
    if(link){
        this.current.href = '#';
        this.current = link;
    }else{
        this.current = this.links[0];
    }
    this.current.href = null;
}
```

because

```
this.current.href = null;
```

produces

```
<a href="null">Link</a>
```

Also I tried `this.current.href=""`, and `this.current.disabled=true`, but neither of them works.
How I can achieve `<a>Link</a>`?

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533406/how-to-disable-a-html-tag

Comment: Have you tried removeAttribute? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.removeAttribute

Comment: To remove an attribute from an element  use removeAttribute

Comment: @J Max Yes but that doesn't help. As I described I'm not looking to prevent the default action of a link nor making it "display: 'none'", i'm looking for something else.

Comment: @ zdyn, @ Musa, thank you. removeAttribute does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 38):

try this [removeAttribute("href")](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp)

Comment: Thank you. removeAttribute does exactly what I need.

Comment: might consider updating link to MDN -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute

Answer (score 3):

Try the attached code snippet. 
It uses javascript and currently removes the link function to the third link.
You can easily adapt it by adding more lines in javascript to reflect the lines you want to remove the link (but keep text).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<a id="test-1" href="test-1">test-1</a>
<a id="test-2" href="test-2">test-2</a>
<a id="test-3" href="test-3">test-3</a>

<script>
document.getElementById("test-1").removeAttribute("href");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```