# How to change e.preventDefault() from disabling links of children anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say we have HTML structure like this:

```
<ul id="dropdown-download-links">
  <li>
    <a href="foo.html">Foo</a> <!-- Don't want this clickable, but cannot remove it -->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="bar.html">Bar</a></li>
      <li><a href="baz.html">Baz</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li><!-- .. same style structure here .. --></li>
 <li><!-- .. same style structure here .. --></li>
</ul>
```

So you click on **Foo** and then it toggles **Bar** and **Baz** both of which SHOULD be clickable as `target=_blank` pdf documents. The obvious problem is because of `e.preventDefault()` none of the links work as they should. The relevant jQuery is here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul#dropdown-download-links > li > a").unbind().click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var ulContainer = $(this).closest("li").find("ul");
    $(ulContainer).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Can anyone see a way in which the **Bar** and **Baz** links would work despite using `e.preventDefault()`? So that the original parents which were themselves supposed to be links act as clickable elements that unfold the new links?

Comment: With the code you've shown, Bar and Baz would not be affected because they do not match the selector passed to the event registration, `ul#dropdown-download-links > li > a`.

Comment: The HTML is just an example, I can re-examine but I think the selector still doesn't match the children links which are not working.

Comment: Well we can only help based on the code you post. But right now, that JS has nothing to do with those Baz and Bar links, so the question is void. If those links aren't working, it's for another reason that wouldn't be clear without seeing your actual, wider code.

Comment: The most accuarete example of the code is this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o8fdhke5/1/

Comment: The black boxes (which normally are much smaller icons and have some text would be clickable but as you can see they are not. It conveys the same problem.

Comment: Sure, but Fiddles are supplementary. In order to help you, it's reasonable to expect all relevant information to be in the question :)

Comment: There's no `preventDefault()` in your code shown here. `stopPropagation()` does something different. `unbind()` is also likely unnecessary, if it's truly being run on document ready.

Comment: @HelloWorld your jsfiddle works fine, watch your console, maybe there are errors, as i saw on jsfiddle links don't work because they are linked on your local webserver and they are blocked by a browser for `mixed content`, the links have `HTTP` but page is loaded by `HTTPS`.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there are better ways to do it but you could try to just remove the href attribute tag with 'removeAttribute("href")'

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17387382/11697704

Comment: This is the best answer and the only that I will think that'll work with my rigid serve fed structure. Is there an easy jQuery alternative to it?

Comment: This link sums it up quite well: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-remove-attribute-from-an-html-element-in-jquery.php

Comment: IMO, if a vanilla JS method works for the job, there's no need to resort to a big library like jQuery to do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple CSS solution using [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)?

```js
// Set the event handler on the <li>, not the <a>
$("ul#dropdown-download-links > li").click(function(e) {
  $(this).find("ul").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
a[href="foo.html"] { pointer-events:none; } /* Now, it can't be clicked! */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="dropdown-download-links">
  <li>
    <a href="foo.html">Foo</a> <!-- Don't want this clickable, but cannot remove it -->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="bar.html">Bar</a></li>
      <li><a href="baz.html">Baz</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li><!-- .. same style structure here .. --></li>
 <li><!-- .. same style structure here .. --></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it will remove click event for sliding children

Comment: my typo, sorry, he wants to click on a link but this CSS will disable click event, that will not work for this case

Comment: @IvanKaraman I don't think you've read the requirements. He does NOT want the link to be clickable. Look at his own comment next to it.

Comment: I saw his jsfiddle example, this link is for opening a dropdown menu, but I like your answer, I didn't think about this CSS prop as a solution...

Comment: @IvanKaraman If that's the case, the event can just be added to the `li` parent, rather than the `a`. Answer updated. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `children` method instead `>` it's better for performance, this code doesn't have an affect on children links, you sure that problem in this code?

solution with removing attr `href` will not work for you, because these links will reload a page...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul#dropdown-download-links").children('li').children('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next("ul").slideToggle();
  });
  
  // empty href attr doesn't prevent page reload
  const $second = $("ul#dropdown-second");
  if($second.length) {
    $second.children('li').children('a').attr('href', '');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>With 'preventDefault'</h2>
<ul id="dropdown-download-links">
  <li>
    <a href="foo.html">Foo</a> <!-- Don't want this clickable, but cannot remove it -->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="bar.html">Bar</a></li>
      <li><a href="baz.html">Baz</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li><!-- .. same style structure here .. --></li>
 <li><!-- .. same style structure here .. --></li>
</ul>
<h2>With removed 'href' attribute</h2>
<ul id="dropdown-second">
  <li>
    <a href="foo.html">Foo</a> <!-- Don't want this clickable, but cannot remove it -->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="bar.html">Bar</a></li>
      <li><a href="baz.html">Baz</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
    <a href="foo.html">Foo</a> <!-- Don't want this clickable, but cannot remove it -->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="bar.html">Bar</a></li>
      <li><a href="baz.html">Baz</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
    <a href="foo.html">Foo</a> <!-- Don't want this clickable, but cannot remove it -->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="bar.html">Bar</a></li>
      <li><a href="baz.html">Baz</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li><!-- .. same style structure here .. --></li>
 <li><!-- .. same style structure here .. --></li>
</ul>
```