# angular ng-if for opening and closing tag but leave contents alone - optional tag

Tags: angularjs

I have hit this a couple times, where I want to selectively render a tag on a condition but leave the contents. My use case is a directive when I have an optional link, so I want to render the opening and closing `<a>` tags but leave the contents alone in either case.

```
<a ng-if="condition"><p>Render me always</p></a>
```

Comment: There is no way to tell a browser to conditionally use a closing tag regardless of framework used. You always need to consider the whole element

Answer (score 4):

The only way to do it in Angular without writing custom directive is to use two ngIf conditions:

```
<a ng-if="condition">
    <p>Render me always</p>
</a>

<p ng-if="!condition">Render me always</p>
```

Comment: This is the best quick & dirty solution, but as @dfsq alluded to, writing a directive would be, IMO, a better solution

Comment: @jusopi I actually don't think this is very good idea to write a directive for this. It's not very common thing to do I think, so much simpler just to go with two ngIf's. Maybe not the most elegant solution but still.

Comment: you're right, a directive is rather overkill for his particular usecase.  After reading this, I proposed an ng-class solution since this is really a cosmetic issue currently.  Of course that could change if it encompasses more than how a link should appear.

Comment: What I have done to date, is to have an ng-include <script id="foo"> and then have two <a ng-include="'foo'" ng-if="condition"> at least your fragment is in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this particular use case, this seems to be more of a cosmetic issue.  Would not the `ng-class` directive not work for this?

```
<a ng-class="{'non-link':boolCondition}"><p>...contents</p></a>
```

CSS is responsible for the basic look & feel so create a style that reflects that and then you needn't worry about duplication or directives, etc.

```
.non-link {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

ref - [Is it possible to make an HTML anchor tag not clickable/linkable using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727659/is-it-possible-to-make-an-html-anchor-tag-not-clickable-linkable-using-css)

Comment: I wound up using a similar technique, but doing ng-disabled, as I want to neuter the link.