# Only follow a link within a certain media query

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with some text in it and a link around it.

```html
<a href="mypage.html">
   <div>
      Text goes here ...
   </div>
</a>
```

However, I only want the link to work at a certain page width, namely less than or equal to 625px. Something like this:

```css
a {
   link-works: no;
}

@media (max-width: 625px){
   a {
      link-works: yes;
   }
}
```

The code above is obviously just an illustration – but can this be done with CSS? Or will I need a javascript solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "follow link"? I don't understand the expected behavior, maybe [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)?

Comment: You are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727659/is-it-possible-to-make-an-html-anchor-tag-not-clickable-linkable-using-css

Comment: @AlonEitan I mean if the link should work or not. If page width is > 625px, I want nothing to happen when you click on the link. If it is < 625px, I want the link to work as normal.

Comment: @Snuwerd Thank you very much, I will try that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use property called `pointer-events`

```
a {
   pointer-events: none;
}

@media (max-width: 625px){
   a {
      pointer-events: all;
   }
}
```

Comment: The pointer-events property defines whether or not an element reacts to pointer events. :)