# css print friendly version - disabling links

Tags: css

I have a page with many links. and Have a button to print, clicking on that will be print.css included. In print preview version of the page remain all the links intact.

Is there a way to disable all the link in print preview? i.e. they are no more clickable.

Comment: How is this really a problem? You can't click links on a piece of paper.

Comment: if I see the print preview of this page (with FX) I cannot click any link included.

Comment: This is a custom print preview you're talking about? You're displaying an HTML page with the print CSS activated? Not the browser native print-preview?

Comment: This question seem to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-a-link-using-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this isn't disabling the links, but this is along the lines of print preview and links. Here's an option that you can add to your css so links will print much nicer: http://davidwalsh.name/optimize-your-links-for-print-using-css-show-url

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't disable the links as much as style them the same way as regular text, since the *intent* of clicking on Print Preview is to prepare to print the page, where the links won't work anyway.

If you're still set on disabling links, you can try this query code. Assume that your body has a class called `print` on it:

```
$("body.print a").each(function(a) { $(a).html(a.innertext); });
```

The above is pseduocode and was off the top of my head at 8:30 AM. I would just save yourself the trouble and make links look like surrounding text.