# Disabling a tag inside div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to disable 'a' tag inside div using jQuery.

The structure is like:

```
<div id="xyz"><a style="cursor:pointer;" href="abc.php">xxxx</a></div>
```

On a particular action:

1. `cursor: pointer` property should go away
2. action on 'a' tag should not work
3. 'a' tag should looks like non clickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You can use this css lines

```
#xyz a{
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

[Disable link using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-a-link-using-css/4416239#4416239)

Comment: These aren't supported in IE < 10.

Comment: Oh... Thank for your info... Sorry I am an IE hater :)

Answer (score 3):

Here you are:

```
$("#xyz a").css("cursor", "auto").removeAttr("href");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use prevent the default action of a tag using

```
  $('#xyz a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/32jJH/)