# Disabled href tag

Tags: javascript, html

Although that link is disabled, it's still clickable.

```
<a href="/" disabled="disabled">123n</a>
```

Can I make it not-clickable if it's disabled? Should I use JavaScript necessarily?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-a-link-using-css

Comment: Just for clarification: I'm guessing what you mean is that you've disabled the link but the "click" event still fires?

Comment: You can use the pointer-events:none; in css

Comment: You can use

    preventDefault();
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: But why not just remove the href attribute?

Answer (score 313, accepted):

There is no disabled attribute for hyperlinks. If you don't want something to be linked then you'll need to remove the `<a>` tag altogether.

Alternatively you can remove its `href` attribute - though this has other UX and Accessibility issues as noted in the comments below so is not recommended.

Comment: This works, but I would consider it bad UX if you leave the existing CSS on it. The user will click it and think something is broken. You should never allow the user to become confused about what is happening.

Comment: Just adding cursor: none; to the relevant link seems to achieve as much as cursor: none; pointer-events: none;  . . . . At any rate it's enabling a change of page in a single-page app site for me.

Comment: The link would still be focusable and "clickable" (using Enter) using keyboard navigation even if you use CSS cursor or pointer-events, which is probably bad if you're trying to disable something

Either remove the href attribute or turn it into a span

Comment: You can also add `onclick="return false;"` to the anchor tag and perhaps add a `title` attribute that explains that the link is not valid.

Comment: Also, I believe simply clearing out the `href` and leaving the `<a>` would not be ADA compliant.

Comment: If you are using PHP, you can echo out the href along side the disabled attribute E.g, if ($status == approved){echo 'disabled= "" href = "#" '}. Very crude but it works.

Answer (score 530):

With the help of css you will disable the hyperlink. Try the below

```css
a.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<a href="link.html" class="disabled">Link</a>
```

Comment: Please note that this works only in Internet Explorer 11+

Comment: When focus on link tag with tab key and press Enter this property doesn't work.

Comment: Should only be the answer if you don't care about IE9-10

Comment: This also disables the hover event, which means cursor styling doesn't work.  (<span>&#x20E0;</span> <- none of this on your disabled link.)

Comment: also use opacity to differentiate between active and disabled links. `opacity: 0.5;`

Comment: i like this answer better "<a> doesn't have a disable attribute". It provides some kind of solution, not a flat NO.

Comment: Considering that the accepted answer requires you to destroy the link, this answer is a quick fix.

Comment: @MajidBasirati I know it's an old post but I wanted to give an easy solution to the tab issue. You can always use `tabindex="-1"` inside your anchor tag in order to disable it.

Comment: i like to use cursor: not-allowed; instead of cursor default

Comment: @BrayamValero what is the tab issue ? I add these in my css when i press tab it doesn't select it..

Comment: The `cursor: default;` is redundant. `pointer-events: none` disables all mouse interaction including the `cursor` property. If you want to change the `cursor` property, you need to apply it to the parent element.

Answer (score 101):

You can use:

```
<a href="/" onclick="return false;">123n</a>
```

Comment: will not work if there is already a function as a handler for click event

Comment: @rahulshukla There are catpure events which can catch events early. (https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)

Answer (score 88):

You can use one of these solutions:

### HTML

```
<a>link</a>
```

### JavaScript

```
<a href="javascript:function() { return false; }">link</a>
<a href="/" onclick="return false;">link</a>
```

### CSS

```
<a href="www.page.com" disabled="disabled">link</a>

<style type="text/css">
    a[disabled="disabled"] {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
</style>
```

---

Answer (score 47):

Try this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="cursor: default;">123n</a>
```

Comment: Correct, I always use href="javascript:void(0)"

Comment: This is also a nice touch, if you you still want to retain the function of right click like "copy link"

Comment: href='javascript:;' - that is enough already - href="javascript colon semicolon"

Answer (score 23):

The [`<a>` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2) doesn't have a `disabled` attribute, that's just for `<input>`s (and `<select>`s and `<textarea>`s).

To "disable" a link, you can remove its `href` attribute, or add a click handler that returns false.

Comment: @rocket Are there any implications of removing the href attribute? I mean, it's supposed to be a mandatory attribute. Not that that sort of thing seems to matter much nowadays.

Comment: @Ringo: Removing the `href` may make the cursor not change when you hover over it.

Answer (score 23):

HTML:

```
<a href="/" class="btn-disabled" disabled="disabled">123n</a>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-disabled,
.btn-disabled[disabled] {
  opacity: .4;
  cursor: default !important;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: probably this is best for bootstrap

Answer (score 18):

**Tips 1: Using CSS**   `pointer-events: none;`

**Tips 2: Using JavaScript**   `javascript:void(0)` 
(This is a best practice)

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
```

**Tips 1: Using Jquery**    `$('selector').attr("disabled","disabled");`

Answer (score 15):

You need to remove the `<a>` tag to get rid of this.

or try using :-

```
  <a href="/" onclick="return false;">123n</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

Letting a parent have `pointer-events: none` will disable the child `a-tag` like this (requires that the div covers the a and hasn't 0 width/height):

```
<div class="disabled">
   <a href="/"></a>
</div>
```

where:

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: You can also apply the "pointer-events:none" style directly to the <a> tag, for example by adding the .disabled class with javascript when you want to disable it. A wrapping <div> is not necessary.

Comment: Wrap not required as demonstrated here: [https://jsfiddle.net/d1owm1d0/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/d1owm1d0/1/) for chrome, firefox, and safari. Are you using a different browser where my demo fails?

Comment: @LesNightingill If the a-tag wraps something it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/d9gwgdyf/

Comment: that's correct @Ferus. I'm not sure why that is true.

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('a').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: This Code is working on right click.So, its not an exact solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can emulate the disabled attribute on a `<a>` tag.

`<a href="link.html" disabled="">Link</a>`

```
a[disabled] {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

We can't disable it directly but we can do the following:

1. add `type="button"`.
2. remove the `href=""` attribute.
3. add `disabled` attribute so it shows that it's disabled by changing the cursor and it becomes dimmed.

example in PHP:

```
<?php
if($status=="Approved"){ 
?>
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" disabled> EDIT
     </a>
  <?php    
}else{
?>
  <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"> EDIT
    </a>
  <?php    
}
?>
```

Comment: The type attribute is for MIME type and there is no "button" type, see [HTML <a> type Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_type.asp). Also disabled is not an attribute of `<a>`

Answer (score 5):

you can disable link using javascript at run time by using this code

> $('.page-link').css("pointer-events", "none");

Comment: Late to the party, but this also removes any cursor css. In my case, I use the "cursor: not-allowed" if a link is disabled.

Answer (score 5):

I have one:

```
<a href="#">This is a disabled tag.</a>
```

Hope it will help you ;)

Comment: Hi Werenverlivitz, welcome. Nice, didn't think you'd be the first person with such answer 7-8 years after!

Comment: It's not disabled, it just goes to the current page, possibly navigating away from current section.

Comment: Ts doesn't allow doing this: "The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible"

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get rid of the pointer you can do this with css using [cursor](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp).

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I use

```
<a href="/" onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to achieve the desired result using an ng-href ternary operation

```
<a ng-href="{{[condition] ? '' : '/'}}" ng-class="{'is-disabled':[condition]}">123n</a>
```

where

```
a.is-disabled{
   color: grey;
   cursor: default;

   &:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best answer is always the simplest. No need for any coding.

If the (a) anchor tag has no href attribute, it is only a placeholder for a hyperlink. Supported by all browsers!

```html
<a href="/">free web counters</a><br  />
<a "/">free web counters</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use buttons and links correctly.

•   Buttons activate **scripted functionality** on a web page (dialogs, expand/collapse regions).

•   Links take you to another location, either to a different page or different location on the same page.

If you follow these rules there won't be any scenario when you need to disable a link. Even if you make a link look visually disabled and blank onclick

`<a href="" ng-click="Ctrl._isLinkActive && $ctrl.gotoMyAwesomePage()"`

You won't be considering accessibility and screen readers will read it as a link and visually impaired people will keep wondering why is the link not working.

Answer (score 2):

Here are various ways to disable the a tag :

> ```
> <a >Link Text</a> remove the href from your anchor tag
> <a href=”javascript:void(0)”/>Link text</a> put javascript:void(0) in href
> <a href="/" onclick="return false;">Link text</a> using return false
> ```
>
> As there is no disabled attributes for anchor tag.
>   If you want to stop anchor tag behavior inside a jQuery function than you can use the the below line in the start of the function :

```
$( "a" ).click(function( e ) {
e.preventDefault();
$( "<div>" )
.append( "default " + e.type + " prevented" )
.appendTo( "#log" );
});
```

[event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Answer (score 2):

I see there are already a ton of answers posted here, but I don’t think there’s any clear one yet that combines the already mentioned approaches into the one I’ve found to work. This is to make the link both appear disabled, and also not redirect the user to another page.

This answer assumes you’re using **jquery** and **bootstrap**, and uses another property to temporarily store the `href` property while disabled.

```js
//situation where link enable/disable should be toggled
function toggle_links(enable) {
    if (enable) {
        $('.toggle-link')
        .removeClass('disabled')
        .prop('href', $(this).attr('data-href'))
    }
    else {
        $('.toggle-link')
        .addClass('disabled')
        .prop('data-href', $(this).prop('href'))
        .prop('href','#')
    }
```

```css
a.disabled {
  cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WordPress, I created a plugin that can do this & much more without needing to know how to code anything. All you need to do is add the selector of the link(s) that you want to disable & then choose "Disable all links with this selector in a new tab." from the dropdown menu that appears and click update.

[Click here to view a gif that demonstrates this](http://wpdevpowers.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/2.-Disable-all-links-with-this-selector.gif)

You can [get the free version from the WordPress.org Plugin repository](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-dev-powers-element-selector-jquery-powers/) to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

**If you need to disabled link on laravel with Javascript, here is my solution:**

Link(blade.php):

```
<a href='/link/to/path' class='btn btn-primary mt-3' onclick='disableLink(this)'>Confirmar</a>
```

.css file

```
.isDisabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

a[aria-disabled="true"] {
    color: currentColor;
    display: inline-block; /* For IE11/ MS Edge bug */
    pointer-events: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

.js file

```
function disableLink(link) {
    // 1. Add isDisabled class to parent element
    link.parentElement.classList.add('isDisabled');
    // 2. Store href so we can add it later
    link.setAttribute('data-href', link.href);
    // 3. Set aria-disabled to 'true'
    link.setAttribute('aria-disabled', 'true');
}

function enableLink(link) {
    // 1. Remove 'isDisabled' class from parent span
    link.parentElement.classList.remove('isDisabled');
    // 2. Set href
    link.href = link.getAttribute('data-href');
    // 3. Remove 'aria-disabled', better than setting to false
    link.removeAttribute('aria-disabled');
}
```

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-disable-links/

Answer (score 0):

Anything in the **href** tag will display at the bottom-left of the browser window when you mouse over it.

I personally think having something like **javascript:void(0)** displayed to the user is hideous.

Instead, leave **href** off, do your magic with with jQuery/whatever else and add a style rule (if you still need it to look like a link):

```
a {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Variant that suits me:**

```
<script>
  function locker(){
    if ($("a").hasClass("locked")) {
         $("a").removeClass('locked').addClass('unlocked');
         $("a").attr("onClick","return false");
    } else {
         $("a").css("onclick","true");
         $("a").removeClass('unlocked').addClass('locked');
         $("a").attr("onClick","");
    }
  }
</script>

<button onclick="locker()">unlock</button>

<a href="http://some.site.com" class="locked">
  <div> 
      .... 
  <div>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can disable anchor tags by returning false. In my case Im using angular and ng-disabled for a Jquery accordion and I need to disable the sections.

So I created a little js snippet to fix this.

```
       <a class="opener" data-toggle="collapse"
                   data-parent="#shipping-detail"
                   id="shipping-detail-section"
                   href="#shipping-address"
                   aria-expanded="true"
                   ng-disabled="checkoutState.addressSec">
                   Shipping Address</a>
     <script>
          $("a.opener").on("click", function () {
           var disabled = $(this).attr("disabled");
           if (disabled === 'disabled') {
            return false;
           }
           });
     </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you just want to temporarily disable the link but leave the href there to enable later (which is what I wanted to do) I found that all browsers use the first href. Hence I was able to do:

```
<a class="ea-link" href="javascript:void(0)" href="/export/">Export</a>
```

Comment: This is invalid HTML, as described at https://stackoverflow.com/q/26341507/1709587. If your motivation is just to keep the href around in your source code so it's easy to edit your source later to restore it, there are ways of doing that that don't involve violating the spec, like using a comment. I'd recommend against writing invalid HTML like this without a solid reason for doing so.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<a href="/" disabled="true" onclick="return false">123</a>
```

Just adding: This works in general, however it wont work if user has disabled javascript in browser.

1) You could optionally use Bootstrap 3 class on your anchor tag to disable the href tag, after integrating bootstrap 3 plugin do

```html
<a href="/" class="btn btn-primary disabled">123n</a>
```

Or

2) Learn how to enable javascript using html or js in browsers. 
or create a pop-up telling user to enable javascript using before using the website

Answer (score -3):

### There is an **easy and clean** way like so:

```html
<a href="/shopcart/">

  <button class="btn" disabled> Make an Order </button>

</a>
```

Having **disabled** attribute on a `<button>` by default does not let clicks go through `<button>` element up to `<a>` element. So `<a>` element does not even know that some clicks happened. Manipulate by adding/removing **disabled** attribute on a `<button>`.

Comment: <a href="/shopcart/"  class="btn">  Make an Order  </a>