# google chrome DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom

I use this

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn disabled">Submit</a>
```

to prevent users submitting the form if they do not input according to the validation rules.

However, when I inspect element through google chrome and just remove the `disabled` class from the source.

Boom, the button turns to an `active` button.

So I am just wondering how to prevent this?

Thanks.

Comment: you can call a javascript function after every 3 seconds, which disables/enables the button after checking the input values @TheQuestioner

Comment: To call a function after evry one/two/three seconds you should study (SetTimeInterval)[http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp]

Comment: @MalikAsif Would SetTimeInterval be too heavy for the app? How about adding an event listener? Once no expected class, a function is then called  to rectify with no time lag.

Comment: To submit are you using PHP on backend. ??

Comment: currently using Rails 4.

Comment: There is one more way that you can call a Rails 4 [server side] file in a javascript function depending on the logic checks and don't create a form [create a simple button and eventHander onclick for that] and pass those variables using XMLHTTP documented well in w3school.com @TheQuestioner

Answer (score 0):

There is no disabled attribute for A tag. If you want to disable hyperlink change it with JS into e.g span tag. Here you have some more solutions

[Disabled href tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955667/disabled-href-tag)