# In html attributes setting disabled = "disabled" not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Edit", new { id = item.UserId }, new { title = "User is not editable" , @class = "edit_btn", disabled = "disabled"})
```

I want to disable ActionLink by setting html attribute disabled ="disabled", but its not working. I am able to get class and title attributes but actionLink is not getting disabled.

Can anyone help.. Where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `disabled` attribute doesn't work in anchor tags. MVC renders what you expect, `disabled="disabled"`, but [browsers just ignore it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955667/disabled-href-tag).

You need to do something different, such as not rendering an anchor at all, but just render the text or in a `span`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `ActionLink`s cannot be disabled using the 'disabled' attribute like a button or a select box. You could write some JavaScript that could mimic disabling a hyperlink, but I would recommend changing your html to a button or something similar instead of a hyperlink if you want to disable it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information.. I make it working using span.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using javascript return false

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Account(s)", "CreateAccount", null, new { @class = "btn btnblack", @onclick = "javascript:return false;"})
```