# Disable button .Net Core MVC view

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have button in my view.cshtml file:

```
<td>
    @if(@ViewBag.loading == false){
        @Html.ActionLink(
            "Run Test",
            "RunSingleTest",
            new { testName=@item.Test_type, id=@item.Id},
            new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
    }
</td>
```

Which triggers method in `HomeController.cs`:

```
public IActionResult RunSingleTest(string testName, int id)
{
    _service.RunSingleTest(testName, id);
    var items = _service.GetDetailsById<List>(id);
    return View("TestDetails", items);
}
```

I want to disable this button when user clicks on that button. Should I do it with JQuery/Javascript? How do you pass that button id to script and where to put that id?

Comment: that is an anchor and anchors don't have disable property. You could either `href="javascript:void(0)` or `return false` via jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with plain HTML element. Also I don't see any benefit of disabling button on click since you want to let users know that this button should not perform more. Better put it disabled when it renders.

```
@if(ViewBag.loading == false){
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info btn-disabled" id="@item.Id" testName="@item.Test_type">Run Test</a>
}
```

or if you would like disable it literally then go with jQuery with giving an element a specific class -

```
<a href="/RunSingleTest" class="btn btn-info myBtn" ...> Run Test </a>

$('.myBtn').on('click',function(e){
  $(this).addClass('btn-disabled');
  e.PreventDefault() //preventing to navigate
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605082/in-html-attributes-setting-disabled-disabled-not-working) you can not just set the `disabled` property on the actionlink.  [Instead here shows that you can do it with jQuery Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846845/mvc3-how-to-disable-enable-actionlink)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Run Test", "RunSingleTest, 
       new { testName=@item.Test_type, id=@item.Id}, 
       new { class = "btn btn-info linkdisabled" })
```

**CSS**

```
.linkdisabled{
   cursor:text;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$function(){
    $(".linkdisabled").click(function(){
        return false;
    }
}
```