# How to make a Bootstrap navbar item unclickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

In the navbar [example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/) on the bootstrap site, I would like to programmatically make one of the Navbar items (let's say the About link) disabled/unclickable.

I've tried .addClass('disabled'), .removeClass('active'), but nothing seems to work.

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: This question should answer yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955667/disabled-href-tag. For more info about the proper use of disabled see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a click on a menu item not do anything, you can use the following jQuery syntax to disable its effect:

```
$(/* jQuery selector for menu item */).click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Then you can style the button with a "disabled" or gray color if you desire, so that the user knows it is unclickable. This solution is compatible with all browsers that support jQuery.

Here is a JSFiddle demo of this solution (thanks to @Adjit in the comments!): http://jsfiddle.net/7a2p8jjn/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `pointer-events: none` as the style of the element.
Example with jquery:

```
$('.navbar-nav').find('a[href=#about]').css('pointer-events', 'none')
```

p.s.: as @maximillian-laumeister said this solution is [not compatible with IE10 and earlier](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).

Comment: Be careful as this solution is [not compatible with IE10 and earlier](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).

Answer (score 1):

just add class .disabled

```
<li class="disabled"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
```

and then in your javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".nav li.disabled").click(function() { return false; });
});
```

[here you can see an example](https://jsfiddle.net/3e6a0ooh/)

of course you can add a class **disabled** to the item with [jQuery addClass method](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) also