# Hide Button only on complete list

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, button

Here is my code:

```
<div class="btn-wrapper pull-left">
    <a target="__blank" href="<?php echo $burl.'/print_delivery?
    id='.$value['order_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span 
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Print
    </a>
</div>
```

I want to disable this button when my order status is completed.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use a semantic `<button>` element instead? Then you can just add the `disabled` property.

Answer (score 0):

Hope, This will help you.

```
<div class="btn-wrapper pull-left">
    <a target="__blank" href="<?php echo $burl.'/print_delivery?
    id='.$value['order_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" <?php if (condition here){ ?> disabled <?php   } ?>><span 
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Print
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: a tag do not support `disabled` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955667/disabled-href-tag

Comment: I am really sorry, I thought of button.

Answer (score 0):

it would be easy with `Button` to disable with `disabled` property but you can add condition to your link as per your current code:

```
<div class="btn-wrapper pull-left">
    <a target="__blank" href="<?php echo ($value['status'] == 'completed') ? $burl.'/print_delivery?
    id='.$value['order_id'] : '#' ; ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span 
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Print
    </a>
</div>
```

assumed status would be like this :  `$value['status'] == 'completed'`

fly.. you can also add link to button using javascript.

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://google.com';" value="Go to Google" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="btn-wrapper pull-left">
<a target="__blank" <?php if($data['order_status'] =="Completed"){ ?>   <?php   }else{ ?> href="<?php echo $burl.'/print_delivery?
id='.$value['order_id']; ?>"<?php } ?> class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ><span 
class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Print
</a>
```

OR

```
<div class="btn-wrapper pull-left">
<a target="__blank" <?php if (condition to activate button here){ ?>  href="<?php echo $burl.'/print_delivery?
id='.$value['order_id']; ?>" <?php   } ?> class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ><span 
class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Print
</a>
```

Hope these will help you

Comment: this is my status 

$data['order_status'] = ['wc-processing'=>'Processing', 'wc-on-hold'=>'On Hold', 'wc-completed'=>'Completed', 'wc-pending'=>'Pending'];