# Disable <a> tag if condition true in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

My HTML code was

```
<li >
  <a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/uploadSales'); ?>" id="uploadsales">
  <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-lg"></i> Upload Sales
  </a>
</li>
```

and my php code to disable anchor tag is

```
<?php
  $roleid=$this->session->userdata('roleid');
  if($roleid === '1') 
  {
    echo '<script> $("#uploadsales").prop("disabled", true); </script>';
    </script>';
  }
?>
```

I have to used same code to disable button in php without codeigniter it is worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabled href tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955667/disabled-href-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `<script></script>`.Go for ternary operator,check condition and based on that remove the whole link itself.

```
<?php
   $roleid=$this->session->userdata('roleid');
?>
<li >
    <a href="<?php  echo ($roleid ==1) ? 'javascript:void(0)' : base_url('admin/uploadSales'); ?>" id="uploadsales">
    <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-lg"></i> Upload Sales
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: thanks bro but its not only by roleid=1 if i need to block this also role id=3 how can we set and if alert show message like only particular roles can access is great friend.

Comment: use `in_array()` like `<?php  echo (in_array($roleid,array(1,3)) ? 'javascript:void(0)' : base_url('admin/uploadSales'); ?>`

Comment: @Ram  you can pass as many values inside array for which you want to restrict. BTW glad to help you :):)