# disable button still clickable

Tags: button, bootstrap-4

I have this code for my button(PHP):

```
echo "<a href='inkomend_uitgaand_pp.php?id=" . $productid . "&in=".TRUE. "&uit=".TRUE."'class='btn btn-primary btn-default' disabled>Inkomend/Uitgaand</a>";
```

But the button is still clickable. How can I make sure that it is not clickable anymore

Comment: I don't think you can disable `<a>` tag

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/how-to-disable-a-link-using-only-css

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable a `<a>` tag, what you can do is remove tag altogether, or the href attribute.

More details here: [Disabled href tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955667/disabled-href-tag)