# How to disable Back and Next pagination buttons?

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have made a subpage where I have included a pagination to move between the data of the table, but I have a problem: Where I show the first data is in productlist ?Page=1 or productlist.php but when I am in the first page I lets hit the "Previous" button and it takes me to ?page=0 and it gives me an error since that page doesn't exist. Does anyone know how to disable the "Previous" buttons on the first page and "Next" on the last page? Thank you very much to all.

My code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/addproductos.css?ver=5">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sidebar.css?ver=6">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css?ver=4">
<style>
#main-information {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 3%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
} 
.content-header {
    padding: 10px .5rem;
}
.well {
    min-height: 20px;
    padding: 19px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
.pagination > li > a
{
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
}
</style>
<link rel="icon" href="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/423/423080.svg" >
    <title>LISTA DE PRODUCTOS - PABLOWEBDEV.COM</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<?php
session_start();
require 'lib/checklogin.php';
?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php
    require 'lib/header.php';
    require 'lib/sidebar.php';
    ?>
    <div id="main-information">
    <div class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Lista de productos</h1>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Lista de productos</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Index</li>
            </ol>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div> <!--- content header --->

<?php
require 'logic/conexion.php';
$limite=10;
 $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
 $start=($page - 1) * $limite;

$result=$conexion->query("SELECT * FROM productos LIMIT $start, $limite");
$customers=$result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$result1=$conexion->query("SELECT count(id) AS id FROM productos");
$custcount=$result1->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$total=$custcount[0]['id'];
$pages= ceil($total/$limite);

$previous= $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;
?>

<div class=container>
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col">Precio compra</th>
      <th scope="col">Precio venta</th>
      <th scope="col">Link</th>
      <th scope="col">Sección</th>
      <th scope="col">Ganancia</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
        foreach($customers as $customer) : ?>
    <tr style="color: black;">
            <td style="background-color:#DEE0E3;"><?= $customer['id']?></td>
            <td style="background-color:#DEE0E3;"><?= $customer['nombre']?></td>
            <td style="background-color:#DEE0E3;"><?= $customer['precioinicial']?>€</td>
            <td style="background-color:#DEE0E3;"><?= $customer['precioventa']?>€</td>
            <td style="background-color:#DEE0E3;"><?= $customer['link']?></td>
            <td style="background-color:#DEE0E3;"><?= $customer['seccion']?></td>
            <td style="background-color:#DEE0E3;"><?= $customer['ganancia']?>€</td>          
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div> <!---- TERMINA CONTAINER ---->
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
    <li class="page-item" >
      <a class="page-link" href="listaproductos.php?page=<?= $previous;?>">Anterior</a>
    </li>
    <?php for($i = 1; $i<=$pages; $i++) : ?>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="listaproductos.php?page=<?= $i; ?>"><?= $i; ?></a></li>
    <?php endfor;?>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="listaproductos.php?page=<?= $next;?>">Siguiente</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav> 


    </div>  <!-- TERMINA MAIN INFORMATION --->
</div> <!-- TERMINA WRAPPER --->

 <!--- TERMINAR IF PAGE=0 DISABLE BUTTONS ---->
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Comment: At the previous anchor tag do something like ```<?= $page <= 1 ? 'disabled="disabled"' : "" ?>```

Comment: Where? Can you edit me with code pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the current page is less than or equal to 1. If then add a `disabled` class to the anchor tag. And by using `CSS` you can disable an anchor tag.

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
    <li class="page-item" >
        <!-- here is the previous button disabling code -->
        <a class="page-link <?= echo $page <= 1 ? 'disabled': ''; ?>" href="listaproductos.php?page=<?= $previous;?>">Anterior</a>
    </li>
    <?php for($i = 1; $i<=$pages; $i++) : ?>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="listaproductos.php?page=<?= $i; ?>"><?= $i; ?></a></li>
    <?php endfor;?>
    <li class="page-item">
        <!-- here is the next button disabling code -->
        <a class="page-link <?= echo $page >= $pages ? 'disabled': ''; ?>" href="listaproductos.php?page=<?= $next;?>">Siguiente</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And the [CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27057625/4610740) is

```
a.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```