# how to Disable / Enable button in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I want to check the Article's Status, if `true` the `Edit` button will be disabled else the user can click and switch to the `Edit` page. How to use it?

```
                    return '<a href="Student/EditArticle/' + data + '" class="btn btn-success mr-1"> Edit </a>';
                }}
        ],
        order: [1, 'asc']
    });
```

Comment: You could just return the string " Edit ".  That will take up the same space and not be clickable.

Comment: It came up when I hadn't done the status check, I tried it but it wasn't successful so I left it there and asked the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column render function you are using:

```
render: function (data) { ... }
```

is capable of accessing all the data in the current row. Its full signature is:

```
render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) { ... }
```

So, you can use the `row` parameter to access other columns in that row, such as `row.status`:

```js
{
  data: 'id',
  className: "center",
  title: 'Actions',
  render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
    if (row.status === true) {
      return '<a href="Student/EditArticle/' + data + '" class="btn btn-success mr-1"> Edit </a>';
    } else {
      return '<a href="Student/EditArticle/' + data + '" class="btn btn-success mr-1" disabled> Edit </a>';
    }
  }
}
```

You can see further details and examples [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render).

---

It is worth looking at why the `type` parameter is provided and how it is used. It basically helps you to provide multiple versions of a value - one value for the table display (the HTML link); a different value for sorting; another value for filtering, and so on.

So, for example, for your clickable link, you may prefer the sort and filter values to be simply the `data` value (without any of the extraneous HTML).

But this is completely optional - you don't have to use it. See [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) for more info.

---

**Update:**

I forgot that a hyperlink cannot be disabled in the same way as a button (so you cannot use "disabled"). Instead, you can look at [these approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955667/disabled-href-tag/13955695), or do what TimRoberts suggested in your question's comments. Having said that, the render function with the row parameter should be what you need.

```
else {
  return 'Edit'; // or, alternatively: return ''
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't seem to work. It can still be clicked without being disabled as desired.

Comment: That is my mistake - I forgot that a hyperlink cannot be disabled in the same way as a button (so you cannot use "disabled"). Instead, you can look at [these approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955667/disabled-href-tag/13955695), or do what TimRoberts suggested in your question's comments. Having said that, the render function with the `row` parameter should be what you need.