# Can anyone disable a class from being clickable using Javascript using CanvasLMS theme editor

Tags: javascript, html, canvas-lms

```
        <a class="merge_user_link" href="Our Link">Merge with Another User</a>
```

I am unsure on how to disable the class "merge_user_link" from being clickable using Javascript

I have tried the following code:
$( name_and_email ).removeClass( 'merge_user_link' );

Any Advice

Comment: An `<a>` element does not have a `disabled` attribute, which would prevent click events from happening. But you could remove the `href` to make the click do nothing.

Comment: if you use js, you can attach a click handler and use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) - or you could use css [pointer-events: none](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#none) - although that would mean you couldn't select the text either

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabled href tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955667/disabled-href-tag)