# vue3: Optionally turning RouterLink into a link

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component, vue-router

I checked the docs but before opening a vue feature request I'd like to be sure if it's implemented already.

I'd like 'My link text' to optionally become a link without having to duplicate the content of the link tag. I'm currently doing this:

```html
<RouterLink v-if="hasLink" :to="/my_destination">
  My link text
</RouterLink>
<div v-else>
  My link text
</div>
```

I'd like something like this

```html
<RouterLink disabled="!hasLink" :to="/my_destination">
  My link text
</RouterLink>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<RouterLink>` will be rendered as an anchor tag by default, which does not have `disable` attribute (see [a related Stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955667/disabled-href-tag) and [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attributes)). If you want to achieve this, I'd suggest using class binding for this purpose.

---

Template code:

```
<RouterLink :class="{ disabled: isDisabled }" :to="/my_destination">
  My link text
</RouterLink>
```