# Prevent HTML contents from being interacted with

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, event-handling

I have a site menu  which sits underneath an overlying  and is revealed by clicking on a button on the overlying , which slides it aside.

What I want to do is, while the site menu is open, prevent the overlying  (everything but the menu button, ideally) from being interacted with.

I can do this by hiding and showing a container that sits over top of all the overlying content, but I was wondering if there's a way to just set some sort of property with CSS (best option) or javascript to disable click / touch events on the overlying . Any ideas?

Comment: What is inside of your `div` that you don't want interacted with? Or is it the `div` itself rather than it's children?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JQuery modal overlay to prohibit the user from using anything else but whatever is in the modal div.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Comment: Thanks - this is a good idea, but I don't want to have to include jquery ui if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

When the menu is open, add this attribute to whatever controls you would like to disable

```
onclick="return false;"
```

Then remove the attribute when the menu is closed. This will prevent the default action from occuring.

You can do this without adding an attribute by using this code:

```
document.getElementById("myElement").onclick = function() { return false; }
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS is about the look, not the behavior. So you [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-a-link-using-css) enable or disable elements by applying CSS to them.

Your solution with an overlay is quite capable, i would do it this way too. Note that your overlay can be transparent or semi-transparent.

It is possible to be solved by overriding the click event with Javascript, but why bother creating a complicated solution (you'll have to redefine the `onclick` event on every element and then somehow set it back to normal) if you've already got a short clean solution?

As **mbsurfer** has already suggested, a quick way of disabling everything except your menu is to use the jQuery UI's `.dialog` with the `modal` option:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#menu" ).dialog({
    modal: true
  });
});
```

More info in the docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/