# Disable <a> click without the help of jQuery/Javascript

Tags: html

Is there anyway to inhibit the click handler on `a` tags in HTML without the help of jQuery/Javascript?

`disabled` only works on `button` and `input`, but I've chosen to use `a` tags in my code. I suppose I can use `span` and simulate the exact `a` styles I currently have, but it would be nice if there's a simple way around this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Javascript? Try onclick="return false;" ... but it's not very pretty. Do you use the "href" Tag?

Comment: Use a span instead of an anchor like you propose. If you don't want something to behave like an anchor, then don't make it an anchor.

Comment: Do you need to have "href" set correctly to some page?

Comment: Try This

.disabled {
        pointer-events: none;
        cursor: default;
    }
<a href="#" class="disabled">link</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `#` as `href` or omit the `href`. The link won't work anymore. As cocco noted, setting `href` to `#` has the disadvantage, that the history gets messed up and the browser jumps back to the top of the page. Nevertheless, the value `#` has been used on numerous pages.

Disabling the `onClick` is not possible, but you can use `onclick="return false"`. This way nothing happens on click.

There is also a partial solution using css (described [in this already answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-a-link-using-css)).

Comment: <a>hello</a> is better than # as it also prevents from changing the hash.

Comment: @cocco: Which way of changing does it prevent? By javascript it's possible to set the attribute via `.setAttribute('href', 'http://something');` as well, so I see no advantage.

Comment: i'm talking about the hashtag '#'. you don'teven need to set the hashtag you can set it to nothing. el.setAttribute('href', '');el.href='';<a>link</a>==disabled.

Comment: @cocco: While it is absolutely correct, that omitting the attribute does the job, I don't understand what you meant with *prevents from changing the hash*. Did you mean that it prevents you from *accidently* changing the href?

Comment: nothing special... 1.i don't like the hash tag on the url if it's not needed. 2.if i remember correctly sometimes if you scrolled down it jumps up to the top on some browsers.

Comment: oh yeah and it messses up history.<- biggest problem

Comment: @cocco: Okay, I wasn't aware of the history-problem, right.

Answer (score 2):

there are many ways to do that..

1.simplest:

```
a.onclick=function(){
 return false
}
```

2.standard/modern:

```
a.addEventListener('click',function(e){
 e.preventDefault()
},false)
```

---

**example** with `class=active` to activate the link.

http://jsfiddle.net/y7vVq/

Comment: I assume there's also no way to do it without Javascript also?

Comment: no.. that is not possible.

Comment: Yes it is possible using CSS

Comment: not in a proper way.. but we can never be shure... so demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: also putting a # inside the href is a solution (btw you need js to change that to) but that moves the page to the top if iremember correctly. or using css3 disabling the click but thats not supported on older browsers.

Comment: pointer-events: none; you mean that?

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="return false"
```

This is the simple way to disable click in a tag