# how to apply process or busy image while performaing ajax call using jsf

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf-2

I want delete a row form datatable using ajax call in JSF. It takes 30 seconds to delete a row. I want to block user activity using process image, or process bar before ajax call complete.

i have put sample code for activation you can refer this as a delete.

```
<p:commandLink id="activateId" rendered="#{var.status.statusId eq 1}"
       value=" Activate " action="#{countryBean.ChangeCountryAdminStatus(var.userCountryPK.user.eid,true)}" update="@form" process="@this" >
    </p:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `onclick` attribute to change the class on some element. Then through your css display the process indicator when the class is present. Don't forget to remove the class once the ajax call returned (either successfuly or faulty).

Comment: sure, look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-a-link-using-css) for that