# Disable click on img tag under anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an img tag under anchor tag, i dont want click on img tag, i tried disabled property, it seems there is no such property for img tag.Please let me know how to disable click on img.

code:

```
<a href="google.com"><img src="sample.png"></img></a>
```

Thankyou

Comment: The `click` event is on the `<a>` element, why not just remove the hyperlink?

Comment: @RajasekharP its working check the fiddle demo jsfiddle.net/gKb6B

Answer (score 3):

With CSS, you can use [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events) property:

```
img {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

You can check browser support for this property [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events).

Btw, `<img></img>` is not valid HTML markup. You need to use `<img />`

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/993Kx/)**

Answer (score 1):

Check this question, is it the thing you want?
[Disable link using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-a-link-using-css)

So that your code will be...

```
<a href="google.com" style="pointer-events: none;  cursor: default;">
    <img src="sample.png" />
</a>
```

By the way, in HTML the img tag has no end tag.
http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_img.asp

Comment: please don't advise w3schools as a reference.

Comment: @user3197584 i want to disable img click not anchor click

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the default behavior we can use **event.preventDefault()** method of the event. Older browsers (ie 7 and below) dont support this method, so we have to use **onclick="return false;"**

**Note:**

I added simple text with in the link, to demonstrate the image click is disabled but when we click the text, the anchor click gets activated.

```
function onimgclick(event) {
    if(event.preventDefault)
        event.preventDefault();
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the html markup should be

```
<a href="google.com"><img onclick="return onimgclick(event)" src="sample.png"></img> HI</a>
```