# Best way to create an <a> link with empty href

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to create a link , and to force the link anchor using javaScript, i tried the following:-

```
<a id="ServerSort" href="#" style="text-decoration:underline">
```

it worked well but the page will loose its current position after clicking on the `<a>` link.

I need the link to have an href, because i need need the mouse to change the cursor when going over it ?

can anyone advice ?

Comment: a `javascript:void(0)` works nicely.

Comment: you can remove the href then just do `a:hover{ cursor: pointer; }` in css

Comment: If it doesn't link anywhere it's not really a link... For that reason I prefer `cursor: pointer;` over `javascript:void(0)` and also because if JavaScript is disabled, the link will break.

Comment: The reason for an empty `href` is probably the wish to disable a link, if so you could use CSS with `style="pointer-events:none;"` alternatively, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32930539/1066234

Answer (score 68):

You can use `javascript:void(0)`

```
<a id="ServerSort" href="javascript:void(0)">
```

you don't need `style="text-decoration:underline"` as  commented by [King King](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679602/king-king)

---

by jQuery you can do it by [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

> Stop the default action of the event .

```
$('#ServerSort').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault(); //or return false;
});
```

Comment: @KingKing roger that sir .

Comment: Using `javascript:void(0)` is invalid -- http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#attr-hyperlink-href

Comment: @jsumners it's just invalid to create a valid link, but of course using the `javascript:` prefix won't create any valid link, it just looks like a link, it allows you to run some script on clicking and in this case it does nothing on clicking. The feature of using `javascript:` prefix on an anchor is implemented by almost major browsers and I believe it will still be supported.

Comment: @KingKing the point is that it _doesn't_ create a valid link. I'll let this do the explaining for me -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/1293130

Comment: @jsumners And I also **agreed that it does not create a valid link**, understand? looks like **you did not understand my previous comment**. For the OP's requirement, he **obviously** does not want a valid link (from his comment **... force the link anchor using javaScript ... **), he wants something like clicking on the link will run some script, so using `javascript:` prefix is the correct choice, although it may not be the best because we can use another element and mimic the link instead and using `javascript:` prefix will require inline script which is not recommended.

Comment: No, I don't understand. You can't say "it's just invalid to create a *valid link*" and then in the same sentence say "it's an invalid link". That makes as much sense as using an invalid protocol in the href attribute.

Answer (score 47):

The best way to do that is to set the href to `#0` like this:

```html
<a href="#0">blabla</a>
```

Here's why: You will NEVER have anything on the page with the ID 0 (if you do, there's a problem there anyways), and since `#0` doesn't exist, the click event doesn't bring you back to the top of page. You do NOT need JavaScript to do that and you should not use JavaScript.

Comment: Hey Bene, i tried this suggestion earlier, but for some reason this appends  "#0" to existing url after click. eg "www.blabla.com/#0". Any thoughts ?

Comment: Well, if you do not prevent the action, it will add the href to the url, exactly as the browser always did. My answer meant to prevent the scroll-back-to-top behavior. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Worked Fine :) 
Suppressed react warning.

Comment: sublime and superior to the "javascript:void(0)" solution, thanks ! :)

Answer (score 7):

```css
 .clickable {
   cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
 <a id="ServerSort" class="clickable">Foo</a>
```

Comment: Ah I was typing up something similar at the same time. +1 - Pointers can be easily controlled using CSS no matter the element. If all you need is a pointer, you don't need an anchor element. A span with class="clickable" works just as well.

Comment: Except using the anchor still allows a real href attribute to be added at some point.

Comment: Hence why I metioned "if all you need is a pointer..." :) Definitely leave as anchor if href might be needed later.

Comment: using `href` will also give you keyboard focusability by default

Answer (score 6):

Use [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

> This method tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be.

```js
function clickme(ev) {
  alert('You stay here!')
  ev.preventDefault()
}
```

```html
<a onclick='clickme(event)' href='https://www.google.com/'>https://www.google.com</a>
```

> The event continues to propagate as usual, unless one of its event listeners calls `stopPropagation()` or `stopImmediatePropagation()`, either of which terminates propagation at once.

---

Alternatively, you can use `onclick='return false'` (either inline or in a function). It will prevent default browser behaviour ([more info](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-cancelation)):

```js
function clickme() {
  alert('You stay here!');
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/" onclick='return clickme()'>https://www.google.com/</a>
```

This approach prevents the event to propagate, though. [More details](https://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/).

Answer (score 5):

A few options exist:

```
<a id="ServerSort" href="javascript:">

<a id="ServerSort" href="javascript://">

<a id="ServerSort" href="javascript:void(0)">
```

These are considered bad practice and I would never recommend something like this for production. I typically use the first option when linking to pages that don't exist during the development phase.

Preferably, I would not use a  at all, I switch to a span in example below:

```
<span id="ServerSort" onclick="return false">Test Link</span>
```

and just style an element accordingly:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    #ServerSort {
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
        #ServerSort:hover {
            color:red;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
</style>
```

I am in-lining the js and just hand writing a  here to show a different approach which avoid the need to override the default  behavior.