# # symbol in URL bar of the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this in my jsx, # is used to stop the link if user click on the a tag.

```
<a target={obj.handlerName === 'detail' ? `_blank` : ''} href={obj.handlerName === 'detail' ? `/products/${id}` : '#'} >{obj.name}</a>
```

but I will have the extra `#` if the handlerName is not equal to `'detail'`

Any clue how to get rid of that?

Comment: replace `#` by `'javascript:void(0)'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to create an <a> link with empty href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940761/best-way-to-create-an-a-link-with-empty-href)

Answer (score 0):

What about using the `includes()` method?

```
<a target={obj.handlerName.includes('detail') ? `_blank` : ''} href={obj.handlerName === 'detail' ? `/products/${id}` : '#'} >{obj.name}</a>
```

Here's some useful reference:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes