# How tell Ember do not fire click event on disabled link?

Tags: events, ember.js, click

I have the link with class 'disabled'.
I don't want that ember process click on this link.

In jQuery I always write:

```
$(document).ready(() ->
  $("body").on("click", "*[disabled], .disabled", (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
  )
)
```

But this not working with ember. How can I do this globally for ember?

Comment: I would do it with CSS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-a-link-using-css

Comment: But as I know css-disabling doesn't work in IE.

Comment: Also it suppress the tooltips. But tooltips on disabled buttons is commonplace.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your ember event handler code.

Comment: I reported the question to https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/4866, hopefully someone will give a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it in your template like this:

```
{{#link-to "some.link" item disabled=methodOrItemProperty}}
  {{item.name}}
{{/link-to}}
```