# How to disable links while displaying rsform submission on frontend joomla?

Tags: html, css, joomla

Please help me out of this. I am using RSForm joomla 2.5 on which while displaying submission on frontend the details coming out are on anchor tag which I don't want. Can anyone suggest me how to disable links.

Thanking you,
Chanadn

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to clearly understand what you're saying.. but '**how to disable links**'.. You can try this:

```
a.disablelink { pointer-events:none;}
```

Comment: @Lodder true, I should have mentioned this will only work on the current versions of all major browsers --> http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer

Comment: A possible alternative might be to use jQuery or Javascript as mentioned on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-a-link-using-css

Comment: @Lodder javascript is definitely a safe alternative, but since the OP didn't tag js, I assumed he's looking for a css only solution..