# jquery displays only the last review

Tags: jquery

Just want to display the reviews using jquery but it displays only the last review. Could you help me please.

```
$.each(data.results, function(i, res) {

        var item = $('<div>'),                    
            head = $('<h4>'),
            info = $('<p>');

        head.html(res.title);
        info.html(res.review_text+'<hr>'); 

        item.append(head,info);

        $("#review_list").html(item);
    });
```

**Update:**

Actually I tried in this way and it worked without using append.

```
 var item = $('<div>'); // moved item outside loop

$.each(data.results, function(i, res) {


            var head = $('<h4>'),
                info = $('<p>');

            head.html(res.title);
            info.html(res.review_text+'<hr>'); 

            item.append(head,info);

        });

 $("#review_list").html(item); // used html outside loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because every time you replace everything with new content.
You can do this:

```
$.each(data.results, function(i, res) {

    var item = $('<div>'),                    
        head = $('<h4>'),
        info = $('<p>');

    head.html(res.title);
    info.html(res.review_text+'<hr>'); 

    item.append(head,info);

    $("#review_list_is_got").append(item);
});
```

Basically you have `html` which will replace the content of the specified item, and `append` which will add to the container you have, and seems what you want.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have a problem when I use "append". It works ok when I press "Load Reviews" link for the first time. But when I press the link twice, it displays duplicate reviews.

Comment: In that situation you have to handle the call to the function differently, for example disabling the button while the call is performed

Comment: actually, I use a link, not a button. Is there a way to disable link?

Comment: yes, there are many ways, have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-a-link-using-css

Comment: I have just updated my question. Could you please have a look on it to check if it is correct.

Comment: Yes it is correct. You are basically doing the same thing, but a little bit less efficient since you are repopulating the `#review_list_is_got` item completely at every cycle.