# Radio button fails to give required message

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following:

- table rows containing radio buttons
- a link named "Issue" that gives a pop up with 1 submit button
- a submit button named "details" that gives a popup

My problem is:

1.) If I click on the link without selecting the radio buttons, I am not getting "required"msg for my radio button instead pop up appears directly.And now if I click on "yes" It shows "radio button required".

2.)I am facing same problem On clicking details button directly without selecting radio button also.

My radio button is:

```
<input type="radio" name="ID[]" value="<?php echo $total; ?>" id="inc_untraced"<?php echo $_POST['ID'][0]==$total ? 'checked':'';?> required />
```

1.) My code for link popup:

```
<a href="#modalDialog1" id="btn">
                        Issue Notice</a>
<div id="modalDialog1" class="modalDialog">
<div>
<table id="pop">
<tr>
<td>Would you like to issue Notice?</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td ><input type="submit" name="details" value="Yes" id="btnYES" formaction="notice.php" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>                  
</div>
</div>
```

2.) My code for pop up using button:

```
<input type="submit" name="details" value="Details" id="btndetails"   />
<div id="element_to_pop_up">
                </div>
```

Jquery:

```
(function($) 
{
    $(function() 
    {

        $('#btndetails').bind('click', function(e) {
        // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
        e.preventDefault();
         var n=$('#inc_untraced:checked').val(); 
                var a=n.split("(!@!)");

                 $("#element_to_pop_up").html("Details are:a[0],a[1] .. /*some details*/");
                $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup();
             });
      });
})(jQuery);
```

Can any one please help me get that "REQUIRED"msg for radio buttons when I click on LINK and BUTTON directly  instead of popup?

PLZ NOTE: I DONT WANT TO USE ALERT BOX .

Please please help me!!

Comment: Hi, Can you please post your code here : http://jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the radio to `true` on unwanted button clicks, or disable the unselected row buttons and enable the only one with the checked radio. That approach would be more user friendly.

Check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/n9v4oe3a/4/

Comment: Could u please elaborate and say.

Comment: Can we disable a link until radio button is clicked?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-a-link-using-css describes it.