# Image container over a link

Tags: html

So, I have links that are automatically generated.

For a specific page I don't want users to click the link (only see that it is there).

Without modifying the code, I am thinking of putting a div container over it with high z-index so that users cannot click it.

Should I embed a 1 pixel image with background repeat that are positioned exactly on top of the link or is there a better way of achieving this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you not just intercept the click with JS? Also, how are you going to create an absolutely positioned `div` element without modifying the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable pointer events using CSS, actually. For example, if you add a class or can identify the `<a>` element in some way, you could use this CSS:

```
a.disabled {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

Browse support for `pointer-events` can be seen [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events).

Credit to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-a-link-using-css).