# Disable html anchor in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am getting a problem in my application, where i want to disable `html` anchor with `css`, I have seen a solution in [Disable link using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-a-link-using-css), which is working fine in `Chrome` and `Firefox`, but when i am opening my page to `Internet Explorer`, It could not be disabling, I have gone through many links but i didn't get any solution for internet explorer, Please help me if you have any helpful link or answer. Thanks in advance

http://jsfiddle.net/7EQJp/

```
<a href="link.html" class="active">Link</a>

.active {
       pointer-events: none;
       cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use pointer-events css property to disable the links but they have known issues with ie. Starting from ie 11 this property is supported. There is a little hack. You should add disabled class to links and add disabled attribute to the link then add css that is given below. Also you need to provide pointer-events none for disabled anchor attribute. After these two this should work in most browsers.

```
a.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}

a[disabled] {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7EQJp/2002/).

Comment: Yeah this trick is working fine in ie. Thanks @Rahul for your answer

Answer (score 2):

CSS way to disable links:

```
a[disabled]{
pointer-events: none;}
```

else you can use javascript to disable links:

```
$("td > a").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Answer (score 2):

Pointer events was originally only Mozilla. It's been adopted in `-webkit-` but unfortunately not in IE. And now that they have Edge. I guess it won't ever be the case.

From the MDN docs:

> Warning: The use of pointer-events in CSS for non-SVG elements is experimental. The feature used to be part of the CSS3 UI draft specification but, due to many open issues, has been postponed to CSS4.

Comment: then means without using javascript we can't disable a link in ie @Jay

Answer (score 2):

i am also facing this type problem. but i use this solution in my code and its working.

```
.disableButton {
    background: #e6eeee none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 2px solid #cdcdcd;
    border-radius: 20px/40px;
    color: #dcd7dc;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    image-rendering: inherit;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    pointer-events: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    display : inline-block;
   }
```