# how to disable a hyperlink to some certain logic.do not want to use pointer events as it does not support ie8

Tags: javascript, css

I want to disable my hyperlink on some certain condition. do not want to use pointer events as it does not support ie8.

Comment: What kind of conditions?

Comment: tried with pointer events that works fine but doesn't support ie
I need some css with my render logic condition

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)**. You'll want to add an event listener for the element that passes through the `click` event of the hyperlink itself:

```js
document.getElementById("link").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Run any additional functionality
  console.log('Event prevented');
});
```

```html
<a id="link" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Comment: looking for css solution.  thanks for this as well . I know we can use prevent default or pointer events

Comment: If you're looking for a CSS-only solution, your question would be an exact duplicate of [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/how-to-disable-a-link-using-only-css) (which states that you should use `pointer-events`). IE8 stopped being supported by Microsoft years ago, and I have no idea why ~1% of people still use it. Simply support every browser apart from IE8, and possibly display a message telling those running IE8 to get a better browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the disabled attribute to the anchor tag and toggle it true/false using javascript with element.setAttribute