# Making only the ::before part of a link clickable in CSS

Tags: css, hyperlink

The titles in my webpage are also a link that anchor to themselves, for accessibility reasons, I cannot really change that.

However, most people would like something in the likeness of  `Title` with only the  being a clickable link.

So my html looks like

```
<h2 id="myid"><a href="#myid">Title</a></h2>
```

And my CSS (so far):

```
h2 a::before { content: " "; }
```

However, I am far from having the wizardry to know what to do next, I tried looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/how-to-disable-a-link-using-only-css?answertab=votes#tab-top) but I don't really know how to "save" the `::before` part from being affected.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit tricky but you could set a fixed width for the  character and overlap the `h2::after` pseudoelement for the entire length of the element *minus* the width of the `a::before` pseudoelement  so the text can't be clicked.

It's worth noting that this will reduce the usability of the page so be careful on using this approach

```css
h2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

h2::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  content: "";
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 1.25em);
}

h2 a::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed yellowgreen;
  width: 1.25em;
}

h2 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="myid"><a href="#myid">Title</a></h2>
```

Comment: That is awesome thanks! Is there a way to save text selection?

Comment: from the snippet above I can select, copy and paste the "title" text

Comment: On firefox 68esr I can select the full "Title" but not sub parts of it like "tle".

Comment: to be partially selectable the text should be clickable: which is what you don't want to happen